# Mapping jQuery object to C# class when performing a post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I read somewhere that it's possible to map a jquery object to a c# class when doing a post like this:

```
$.post("/controller/action", /*object here*/).done(function(){

});
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("action")]
public ActionResult action(MyClassObject obj)
{
    // do something with the obj...
    return obj.param1+obj.param2+obj.param3;
}
```

And the C# class would look like this:

```
public class MyClassObject 
{
    [Required]
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; } 
    public string param3 { get; set; }
}
```

How do I do this with jQuery and .NET MVC 5?

Can someone help me out ?

P.S. This would serve so that I don't need to pass 15 parameters into method like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("action")]
    public ActionResult action(MyClass obj)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("click",".btnAnalyze",function() {
    var data =
    {
        keyword: "1",
        saleRange: "1"
    };
    $.post("/Controller/Action",data).done(function(){

    });
});
```

Can I now, and if yes, to perform a validation against the passed object in my action like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("action")]
    public ActionResult action(MyClass obj)
    {
      if(!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
        // return something, but what?
       }
    }
```

Comment: You mean a Javascript object.  That happens automatically; learn about JSON and model binding.

Comment: @SLaks Yes correct, Any links to some documentation or something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should serialize an actual object as JSON:

```
$.post('/controller/action', {foo: someValue});
```

[Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @SKLaks Once I bind the JS object to my class object, can I then use validation attributes inside the class and check the passed values of objects against the model state to verify whether the user has indeed fulfilled all requirements ?

Comment: Yes; learn about MVC model binding and validation / model state.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
var data = "param1=value1&param2=value&param3=value";
$.post("/controller/action", data ).done(function(){

});
```

At the server side ASP.NET MVC automatically will bind posted data to the right class instance.

Comment: Wait really , that easy? Okay hold on ill test it out :)

Comment: You should pass an object, not form data.

Comment: SLaks, how is it possible then to submit form data classic way ?

Answer (score 1):

If your form maps up to your `MyClassObject` I would just serialise it:

```
var data = $('#form-id').serializeArray();                // form id should be the id of your form
$.post("/controller/action", data ).done(function() {});
```

Comment: Unfortunately i don't use a form .. Just a plain HTML setup with elements from which I pickup the values

Comment: @User987 you probably should wrap your inputs in a form (and prevent the default action for it), otherwise if a user wants to use your site without js (eg some screen readers or other devices do not have js enabled), then your form won't work

Comment: hey by the way, when I pass an object like I've shown above, can I then use the validation attributes in my class and then check against the model state if it's valid or not to display error message if user hasn't entered something ?

Comment: Yes, you can do validation.

Comment: Yes you should be able to but I think the jQuery validation is bound to the form so you would definitely need a form, you can do server side validation using ModelState.IsValid in your controller

Comment: @AndriusJasiukevičius amazing ! Wait hold on i'll update my question so that I can post what I ment exactly

Comment: Btw, i think you should use serialize() and not serializeArray()

Comment: @AndriusJasiukevičius both work, but I use serialise array so that I can push in extra values when I need to - eg passing in a different value based on which button is clicked

Comment: Guys, I've updated my questions so that you can see what I ment

Comment: @User987, you already accepted an answer for this question, perhaps you should ask a new question about the validation (as it isn't really part of your original question), referencing this question

Comment: ModelState.IsValid will give you false, if you will not provide param1 because it is marked as [Required]

Comment: @AndriusJasiukevičius Yes yes,  but how would I display message for each individual field, instead of just sending back some general message to end user ? Like for ex. user entered 1/3 required fields, I'd like to send him back the first next field that he has to validate in order to perform the action successfully

Comment: i suggest to read about [unobtrusive validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

The default model binder in MVC5 will not work if your object contains complex types. I know you said you have a simple list of strings, but I have found this technique to be more successful:

```js
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: yourPostURL,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify(reqData)
}).done(function (response) {
   alert(response);
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourAction(string data)
    {
        Stream req = Request.InputStream;
        req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();

        try
        {
            var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassNameHere>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
    }
```